# Scala Webserver get URL from InputStream

Tags: scala, sockets, http

I am writing a small HTTP Server in Scala.

I have the following code to read from the Sockets Inputstream

```
val input = Source.fromInputStream(s.getInputStream).mkString
```

unfortunately this blocks my thread when I try to access the server with `wget localhost:8008` because I think that the stream is not getting closed.

How can I extract the URL from the HTTP Request that f.e. wget sends to the server from the socket inputstream correctly and without blocking the whole thread?

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using this solution

```
   var list: List[Byte] = Nil

   while(s.getInputStream.available() != 0){
     list = s.getInputStream.read.toByte  :: list
   }

   val byteArray = list.reverse.toArray


   val inputString = new String(byteArray)
```

If somebody has a better answer please post.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me very well:

```
val client = socket
val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream)).readLine
println("Server received:" + in)
```